# How to implement a factory trait that returns generic values with a matching type parameter?

Tags: rust

Consider the following code (simplified but compilable):

```
use std::sync::Arc;

pub trait ActorRef<Message> { /* ... */ }
pub trait Actor<Message> { /* ... */ }
pub trait ActorSpawner {
    /// Spawns a new actor returning an actor ref 
    /// for passing messages to it.
    fn spawn<Message,A,R>(actor: A) -> Arc<R>
        where R: ActorRef<Message>, A: Actor<Message>;
}
```

Is it possible to implement `ActorSpawner::spawn` or to achieve something similar with another signature?

## The idea

The code in the question is simplified to reduce it to the core parts that I couldn't solve.

In general, an `Actor` should have mutable state which is changed by the processing messages (a process method is missing from the example). You can spawn an `Actor` and can communicate with it via an `ActorRef` (the send method is missing from the example).

I want to allow different ways of "spawning" an `Actor`. E.g. the message processing might happen on one thread per actor. Or the processing might be done on a thread pool which is shared by other actors.

Other code might depend on creating further actors. The underlying mechanism used should be abstracted. Since the trait `ActorSpawner`.

## My attempts to solve it

Let's assume that we have some dummy implementations for `Actor` and `ActorRef`:

```
struct NoopActor;
impl<Message> Actor<Message> for NoopActor {}

struct DeadRef;
impl<Message> ActorRef<Message> for DeadRef {}
```

It should now be possible to implement the trait somehow using these dummy implementations.

This is my first attempt:

```
struct DeadActorSpawner;
impl ActorSpawner for DeadActorSpawner {
    fn spawn<Message,A,R>(actor: A) -> Arc<R>
        where R: ActorRef<Message>, A: Actor<Message> 
    {
        Arc::new(DeadRef)
    }
}
```

resulting in this error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:29:18
   |
29 |         Arc::new(DeadRef)
   |                  ^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `DeadRef`
   |
   = note: expected type `R`
              found type `DeadRef`
```

Or another one:

```
struct DeadActorSpawner;
impl ActorSpawner for DeadActorSpawner {
    fn spawn<Message,A,R>(actor: A) -> Arc<DeadRef>
    {
        Arc::new(DeadRef)
    }
}
```

resulting in this error:

```
error[E0053]: method `spawn` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> src/main.rs:25:42
   |
12 |     fn spawn<Message, A, R>(actor: A) -> Arc<R>
   |                                          ------ type in trait
...
25 |     fn spawn<Message, A, R>(actor: A) -> Arc<DeadRef> {
   |                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found struct `DeadRef`
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(A) -> std::sync::Arc<R>`
              found type `fn(A) -> std::sync::Arc<DeadRef>`
```

I have tried numerous other things to no avail including using associated types for the `Message` in `Actor` and `ActorRef`.

Comment: I'd just like to pre-emptively ask for some more information.  The only cogent answer I could give at the moment is: "what you're asking for is impossible".  Can you explain what all the generic types are for?  Do they *really* need to be generic, or is it acceptable for an implementation of, say, the ActorSpawner trait to *dictate* the specific ActorRef/Actor/Message combination to the caller?

Comment: Hi DK, actually it would be acceptable if the ActorSpawner would dictate the types of ActorRefs it produces. But since kers solution doesn't require it, there is no reason to. Thanks for your interest into this question, anyways!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement `ActorSpawner::spawn`

[Yes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=86bcf4601ae8d97ea3dc2cd54ddb3fbd&version=stable&backtrace=0), but there's no useful implementation as I see it

> or to achieve something similar with another signature

I believe you were expecting an `Arc<ActorRef<Message>>` to be returned. So you could use the `DeadActorSpawner` through the `ActorSpawner` trait without knowing about the `Dead`* types.

What you actually did was to attempt to specialize the `spawn` function to return an `Arc<DeadRef>`. I modified your `ActorSpawner` to return a trait-object:

```
pub trait ActorSpawner {
    fn spawn<Message, A>(actor: A) -> Arc<ActorRef<Message>> where A: Actor<Message>;
}

struct DeadActorSpawner;
impl ActorSpawner for DeadActorSpawner {
    fn spawn<Message, A>(actor: A) -> Arc<ActorRef<Message>>
        where A: Actor<Message>
    {
        Arc::new(DeadRef)
    }
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4a0087e18b5a57b21faca4d0d2ae55df&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

Comment: Thank you, @ker! That was something I tried but didn't realise that I need either the nightly rust for or an additional Box.

Comment: I hope, I explained the idea of the code in question now in an understandable fashion. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I extended/changed your playpen a little bit by adding a self argument and a litte example of using the code: http://is.gd/AIWMgs